# Normalizing price data from 1 to 100

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with just 21.5 million rows, representing properties sold across the UK from 1995. For each entry I've calculated a new price based on inflation of that year and now want to normalize this inflated price to assign a value between 1 to 100.

The average price in the table is 240000. The data is skewed in a way that 3/4 of the data is below the average. Max is 150 million, min is 1000

Normalizing the data using the SQL query below results in 20 million properties assigned the normalized price of 1.

```
UPDATE properties p
SET inflatedNorm = round(
    1 + (
        (p.inflatedPrice - MIN_PRICE) * (100 - 1) / (MAX_PRICE- MIN_PRICE)
    )
);
```

What have I done wrong ? Surely 20 million 1s is wrong and there should be a more varied spread of values with most of them being around the average price.

Comment: If all values are integers then you do integer division which cuts off everything after the decimal point. Just a single `1.0` in the calculation instead of `1` makes it a float devision

Comment: @juergend SQL doesn't do integer division. You're thinking of C.

Comment: Can you show some sample data from the table, and the values of `MAX_PRICE` and `MIN_PRICE`?

Comment: Maybe there's a billion pound item in your database.

Comment: The lowest is a 1000 and the highest is 150 million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't round the result!  Let the database store decimal points.  So:

```
UPDATE properties p
    SET inflatedNorm = 1 + (p.inflatedPrice - MIN_PRICE) * (100.0 - 1) / (MAX_PRICE - MIN_PRICE);
```

The other issue is what the prices look like.  I would start with:

```
select max(price), min(price)
from properties p;
```

If the maximum is 100 times the minimum, then you'll see the phenomenon you are seeing.  The range is the only thing important for your calculation, not the actual distribution within the range.

That is, if you considers the net worth of Americans and include Bill Gates in your data, then 99+% of Americans will have a net worth less than 1% of Bill Gates.

Comment: The min is 1000 and max is 150 million. Should I cut off some of the data to even the range?

Comment: @Barrera . . . Well, as you have learned, breaking the range into equal sized bins isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get that. I chucked away the data above 100 million and then got the 99th and 1st percentile and used them as max min